# How not to show the success in Jquery Ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using Jquery ajax like this:

```
function deactivate() {
    var user_info=document.getElementById('user_info').value;
    if (user_info=''){
    alert('Enter password!');
    return false;
    }
    else {
      $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/deactivate/",
                data: {user_info:user_info},
                success: function(data){
                     $('#deactivate_modal').html(data)

                }
            });
        }
}
```

If the user information provided by the user is not correct, the error is shown in div which is perfectly fine but if it's correct I want the page to be refreshed the redirect user to login page. How can I do that?

Comment: `window.location.href = login.php` inside your success function?

Comment: Can you please post an answer. If a error message has to be shown I don't want to refresh the page if success I want to refresh the page.

Comment: If the user details are correct does the server return a response that can be validated?

Answer (score 1):

If your server returns a response (can be anything, html, json, plain text, etc.) then you can just check that in your success function.  The code below expects the server to return a response of 'success' if the user info was correct.  The response can be anything, just replace 'success' with your server's response.

I also noticed that you're using an assignment operator in your first if statement and that your key / value pair needs to have the key wrapped in quotes otherwise it's replaced with the contents of the variable.

Code example:

```
function deactivate() {
    var user_info = document.getElementById('user_info').value;
    if (user_info == '') {
        alert('Enter password!');

        return false;
    }
    else {
        $.ajax({
            type:    "GET",
            url:     "/deactivate/",
            data:    {'user_info': user_info},
            success: function (data) {
                if (data === 'success') {
                    window.location = 'http://www.mydomain.com/myPageAFterLogin'
                } else {
                    $('#deactivate_modal').html(data)
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: your answer is far more comprehensive so i deleted mine and upvoted yours (good work). in the future, though, commenting on someone else's answer when you've provided your own is a real dick move, almost as douchey as downvoting other answers. let's play nice! :)

Comment: Sorry, I posted my answer, refreshed and yours was there.  Otherwise I would have just edited yours.  =)

Comment: Looks like it's having a hard time finding the element with the Id 'user_info', ensure that the ID is correct and that the element is available in the DOM before the code executes.